# Mips Overflow Detection , Printing the Result

Tags: overflow, mips, mips32

i wrote down this simple code just to verify the overflow in Mips Processor for my final test:

```
.data
.text
.globl main
 main:
    li $s0, 2000000000
    li $s1, 2000000000


    addu, $s2 , $s0, $s1

    li $v0, 1
    move $a0, $s2
    syscall
    j end


    end: 

    li $v0, 10
    syscall
```

it of course result in 0xee6b2800, in decimal  -294967296, just because mips encode numbers in two's complement and it recognizes the MSB as the Sign bit( 1, and its negative).
How can i implement a loop for printing ( in the same program) the right value? ( In this case 4 Bil, 4x10^9) 
Thank you very much

Answer (score 7):

Detecting overflow is not difficult if you know both the operands and the result:

```
li $s0, 2000000000
li $s1, 2000000000

addu $s2 , $s0, $s1

xor $t0, $s0, $s2   # $t0 = op1 ^ result
xor $t1, $s1, $s2   # $t1 = op2 ^ result
and $t0, $t0, $t1   # $t0 = (op1 ^ result) & (op2 ^ result)
bltz $t0, overflow
```

Signed overflow occurs when adding two numbers of the same sign results in a number with the opposite sign.

For 32-bit numbers, if `((op1 ^ result) & 0x80000000) == 0x80000000)`, then `op1` and `result` have opposite signs.

Thus, if `(((op1 ^ result) & (op2 ^ result)) & 0x80000000) == 0x80000000)`, then that must mean that `op1` and `result` have opposite signs, AND `op2` and `result` also have opposite signs, therefore `op1` and `op2` must have the same sign. Which is exactly what we wanted to check. The `bltz` is just a simpler way of checking if the most significant bit (0x80000000) is set.

---

To print the value as an unsigned integer you probably have to write your own int-to-string conversion routine, and then print the result string using the `print_string` system call. That's a fairly simple operation, and you should be able to find examples if you do some searching (perhaps not for MIPS specifically, but the algorithm is the same regardless of the instruction set).

Comment: i tried using syscall 36 on Mars ( print unsigned) and i get 4bil printed correctly, but i dont get  your XOR and AND operations, are those for convert in unsigned from two's complement?

Comment: Why not use SRA to get the MSB

Comment: @LudovicoMarzagalli The `xor` and `and` instructions make up for MIPS's lack of processor flags. Most CPUs can automatically detect overflow and set an overflow flag when an addition/subtraction results in a register crossing the `7FFFFFFF-80000000` boundary. MIPS doesn't have that, so this algorithm is needed to tell if this has actually taken place, which can tell the difference between signed overflow (crossing the `7FFFFFFF-80000000` boundary) and unsigned overflow (wrapping around from `FFFFFFFF-00000000`).